# Ninject MVC3 leads to "cannot find file Mvc.sitemap"

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I am trying to use Ninject on a Web project. In Visual Studio I ran

```
Install-Package Ninject.MVC3
```

But now when I run the project I get the error

```
Could not find file '<path>\Mvc.sitemap'
```

What is this Mvc.sitemap file?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the problem by installing:

```
Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5
```

Still don't quite understand why Ninject depends on SiteMap.